# How can I upgrade the TypeScript version in SharePoint 2019 Project？

Tags: 2019, react, typescript, gulp

I'm trying to use `react@17.0.1` and `Fluent8` in a new `SharePoint 2019` project

When running, it shows some `TypeScript` syntax errors like this:

```bash
...
Starting subtask 'tslint'...
Starting subtask 'typescript'...
[typescript] TypeScript version: 2.4.2
Error - typescript - node_modules\@fluentui\react\lib\components\SelectedItemsList\SelectedPeopleList\SelectedPeopleList.d.ts(3,35): error TS1005: ';' expected.
Error - typescript - node_modules\@fluentui\react\lib\components\SelectedItemsList\SelectedPeopleList\SelectedPeopleList.d.ts(4,12): error TS1005: '=' expected.
...
```

How can I upgrade the `TypeScript` version used by the `gulp runtime` ?

SharePoint version:

```
"@microsoft/sp-core-library": "~1.4.0",
"@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset": "~1.4.0",

"@microsoft/sp-build-web": "~1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-module-interfaces": "~1.4.1",
"@microsoft/sp-webpart-workbench": "~1.4.1"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer in [here](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/3007#issuecomment-474052604)

First use npm install your expect `typescript` version in your project

Then, open `gulpfile.js` :

```javascript
const build = require('@microsoft/sp-build-web')

// Add the following code：
const typescriptBuild = require('@microsoft/gulp-core-build-typescript')

typescriptBuild.TypeScriptConfiguration.setTypescriptCompiler(require('typescript'))

// Finish
build.addSuppression(`Warning - [sass] The local CSS class 'ms-Grid' is not camelCase and will not be type-safe.`)

build.initialize(require('gulp'))
```

Finally run `gulp serve`, you will see the new version with typescript:

```bash
Starting subtask 'tslint'...
Starting subtask 'typescript'...
[typescript] TypeScript version: 4.4.3
Finished subtask 'copy-static-assets' after 867 ms
```

Maybe you will have a typescirpt error with ['dateVersion'](https://dreamsof.dev/2020-09-21-typescript-upgrade-breaking-dataversion-get-override-spfx11/)

you can fixed like this

```
// @ts-ignore
protected get dataVersion(): Version {
  return Version.parse('1.0');
}
```

**But even so, `gulp` compiles with `Fluent8` and `react@17`, but it doesn't actually run on workbench projects**

As for `react@17`, `spfx workbench` looks for react from `node_modules/react/dist`, but `react@17` does not have this directory, so a 404 error will be reported

Answer (score 0):

You can use below command to install the specific/latest version of typescript.
you can optionally use `-g` parameter to globall install the Typescript.

> npm install typescript@latest

> npm install typescript@4.4.3  (specify version number you want to install here)

Comment: Installing a newer version of `TypeScript` through the npm command does not change the TypeScript version used when executing the `gulp serve` command. It remains the old version.